# How do I refresh a page with a hash?

Tags: javascript, html

I refresh pages by writing `window.location = window.location;`. However this doesn't work on a page like /page#c22. It will just jump to whereever c22 is. How do I refresh the page?

It does not need to use go to #c22 once refreshed but I am sure there is a more dependable way than `window.location = window.location`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may want to try:

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

> `reload(forceget)`: Reload the document from the current URL. `forceget` is a boolean, which, when it is `true`, causes the page to always be reloaded from the server. If it is `false` or not specified, the browser may reload the page from its cache. ([Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.location))

Answer (score 4):

You can use this:

```
window.location.reload();
```

[The spec for this is here, at the W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/Window/#location-methods)

> This function forces the host application to reload the resource identified by the Location.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
location.reload(true)
```

Answer (score 1):

"[Page auto reload with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296685/page-auto-reload-with-parameters)" is one tried to preserve get parameters.

Probably you wanted to use [location.pathname](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_pathname.asp).