# How to refresh page in JSF on selectOneMenu selection?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a page containing a PrimeFaces (2.2.1) Editor component, a Refresh button and a selectOneMenu, whose selection affects the contents of the Editor, as follows:

```
<p:editor id="uploadedText" value="#{facilityDataUploadBean.uploadedText}"
          width="600" height="180" disabled="true" controls="" />
<h:commandButton value="Refresh" immediate="true" />
<h:selectOneMenu id="skipLines" styleClass="dropdown"
                 value="#{facilityDataUploadBean.skipLines}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{facilityDataUploadBean.skipLinesList}" />
    <f:ajax listener="#{facilityDataUploadBean.importParameterChanged}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

`facilityDataUploadBean.importParameterChanged` updates `facilityDataUploadBean.uploadedText`.  After changing the selectOneMenu value, the operator presses the Refresh button to refresh the page, including the contents of the `p:editor`.  (I cannot simply refresh the `p:editor` using AJAX, because it doesn't re-render correctly, at least in PF 2.2.1.)

It seems like I ought to be able to accomplish the page refresh automatically when the `selectOneMenu` value is changed, but I've been unable to come up with a combination of attributes and events that will do that.  I've tried various combinations of `onchange="submit();"`, `immediate="true"` and `valueChangeListener` on the `selectOneMenu`, as well as `execute="@all/@form"`, `render="@all/@form"` on the `f:ajax` event, all to no avail.  My current workaround is to display a message asking the user to press the Refresh button whenever they change the `selectOneMenu` selection - pretty hokey.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Invoke `window.location.replace(window.location.href)` rather than `submit()` in the `onchange` event, as in:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="skipLines" ... onchange="window.location.replace(window.location.href);">
    <f:selectItems ... />
    <f:ajax ... />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: Once in a while a change to the selectOneMenu doesn't "take" - perhaps the page refresh occurs before the AJAX that sets the value in the backing bean executes.  But I haven't seen it leave the UI in an inconsistent state or showing a different value than is currently held by the backing bean (which is SessionScoped).

Comment: Note that this solution also avoids certificate selection (which could be wanted or unwanted).

Answer (score 3):

please try the `onchange="window.location.reload();"` approach like:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="skipLines" ... onchange="window.location.reload();">
    <f:selectItems ... />
    <f:ajax ... />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

This works just fine in my environment (GF 3.1.1, PF 3.2) but please be aware that there is the possibility of interrupting some ajax functinality.

Hope this helpes, have Fun!

Comment: When I do that, I get the same dialog that [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869721/reload-browser-window-after-post-without-prompting-user-to-resend-post-data) complains about.  The solution, however, is to use `window.location.replace(window.location.href)` rather than `window.location.reload()`, which the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296685/page-auto-reload-with-parameters) tipped me off to.

Comment: Great to hear you found a solution which worked out for you! Cheers!