# How reload jsf page after primefaces upload?

Tags: javascript, jsf, file-upload, jsf-2, primefaces

What a may to reload a jsf page after primefaces upload?

I try with javascript `oncomplete="javascript:window.location.reload()"`, but it's doesn't work:

**xhtml:**

```
<h:form>
    <p:messages showDetail="true"/>  
    <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{revistauploadBean.upload}"
                  mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="false" merge="true"  
                  uploadLabel="Enviar" cancelLabel="Cancelar"
                  oncomplete="javascript:window.location.reload()"
                  label="Procurar PDF" sizeLimit="1000000000" fileLimit="3"
                  allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(pdf)$/" />
</h:form>
```

**Bean:**

```
public void upload(FileUploadEvent event) throws SQLException {  
    LoginAuthentication user = new LoginAuthentication();
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Success! ", event.getFile().getFileName() 
        + " is uploaded.");  
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    // Do what you want with the file        
    try {
        copyFile(event.getFile().getFileName(), event.getFile().getInputstream());
        ConectaBanco mysql = new ConectaBanco();
        mysql.insere("INSERT INTO edicoes VALUES (NULL, '" 
            + mysql.pegaIDrev(user.getNome()) 
            + "', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '" 
            + event.getFile().getFileName()
            + "' );");
        File pasta = new File(caminhoPastaPDF 
            + "/convertidos/" 
            + event.getFile().getFileName());
        pasta.mkdir();
        convertePdf(event.getFile().getFileName());
        FacesMessage msg1 = new FacesMessage("Succesful", event.getFile().getFileName() 
            + " is uploaded.");  
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg1); 
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}  

public void copyFile(String fileName, InputStream in) {
    try {
        // write the inputStream to a FileOutputStream
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(destination + fileName));
        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        while ((read = in.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            out.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        in.close();
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        ////System.out.println("New file created!");
    } 
}
```

There are another ways to do that?
I want to refresh a `<a4j:repeat>`

Comment: uumm, try it without "javascript:". It should be able to perform a reload. BUT you will probably have the problem that you will reload the page with the wrong URL. If you do not navigate with ?faces-redirect=true, then your URL will always lag behind by one page

Answer (score 2):

[`<p:fileUpload />`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileUploadSingle.jsf) has an `update` attribute which, given `@form` value, renders the **whole form** again.

```xml
<p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadController.handleFileUpload}" 
    mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="false"  
    update="@form" sizeLimit="100000" fileLimit="3" 
    allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" />
```

Otherwise, if you want to get rid of ajax features, you also have the [basic fileUpload](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileUploadSimple.jsf) component.

```xml
<p:fileUpload value="#{fileUploadController.file}" mode="simple"/>  

<p:commandButton value="Submit" ajax="false"  
            actionListener="#{fileUploadController.upload}"/>
```

Basically, try not javascripting what is already done!

Answer (score 2):

Please, try to use

```
onsuccess="location.reload();"
```

It works for me pretty well. I am using it to reload my page after hitting on save button to see new uploaded file. It would not work when you use updating all forms
`update="@(form)"`

Comment: See here also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11150042/1599699 `window.location.replace(window.location.href)`

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add at the end of **upload** method:

```
ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
ec.redirect(ec.getRequestContextPath()+"/faces/yourpage.xhtml");
```

to reload the same page. For me it works fine.